# Yii: Cascade delete related record together with file

Tags: php, database, yii

I have an application scheme that looks slightly like this:

```
<?php
class Category extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'category_id'),
        );
    }
    // ...
}

class Post extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'categories' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
            'pictures' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PostPicture', 'post_id'),
        );
    }
    // ...
}

class PostPicture extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'post' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Post', 'post_id'),
        );
    }
    // ... public function deleteFiles() ...
}
```

All relations defined in PHP code also exist in the database with proper foreign keys and `ON DELETE CASCADE` set up (InnoDB). `PostPicture` provides a way to delete associated files.

When I delete a `Category` object via `$category->delete();`, ON DELETE CASCADE on the database level occurs, the picture records get deleted before I can access them and I won't be able to retrieve file system paths.

Completely disabling foreign keys is not very elegant - I would have to implement `beforeDelete` hooks for nearly every model class.

Retrieving all PostPicture rows associated to the Category's posts and calling their `deleteFiles` function in `Category::beforeDelete()` seems like an acceptable solution but is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the objective of onDelete cascade that related records get deleted. If you want to retrieve something then do it prior to delete. If I understand correctly you want to retrieve the filepaths so the files on the system can be deleted as well.

Since you know the records you are deleting find the data and save it and then execute the delete. just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

oncascade is a database setting... so as the database is deleting the child records... the Yii or any PHP code does not "know" that... that's why your object is not deleted and beforeDelete/afterDelete is not called...

[Copied from here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26267-delete-on-cascade/)